# Binding with 2 or more dependency properties

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a textbox in my WPF application and it is currently displaying if a dependency property is set.  I'm wondering if there is a way to display this textbox using an OR statement?

```
<TextBox Grid.Row="1" Height="23" Width="132" Margin="451,30,0,0" 
Text="{Binding Path=PositionName}" 
Style="{StaticResource TextBoxStyleValue}" 
Visibility="{Binding IsDepProp1, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}, 
RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}" />
```

Something like:

```
Binding IsDepProp1 || IsDepProp2
```

Comment: One option is to add a property to your model that calculates the condition.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't just add a new One Way binding to a property that just does `IsDepProp1 || IsDepProp2` under the hood?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMultiValueConverter is a way to go but however you can achieve that using two DataTriggers as well like this:

```
<TextBox Grid.Row="1" Height="23" Width="132" Margin="451,30,0,0" 
         Text="{Binding Path=PositionName}">
    <TextBox.Style>
        <Style TargetType="TextBox" BasedOn="{StaticResource TextBoxStyleValue}">
           <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
           <Style.Triggers>
              <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsDepProp1,
                               RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,
                                       AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}"
                            Value="True">
                  <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
              </DataTrigger>
              <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsDepProp2,
                              RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,
                                      AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}"
                           Value="True">
                  <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
               </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
         </Style>
      </TextBox.Style>
</TextBox>
```

`Default value will be Collapsed` and based on two triggers you can check `if any of the property returns true, set visibility to Visible`.

Comment: Your welcome webdad3. I generally prefer DataTriggers for such small scenarios. Rest is your choice.. :)

Answer (score 2):

I belive you are looking for `MultiBinding`.

Check out: http://tech.pro/tutorial/809/wpf-tutorial-using-multibindings for a good explanation.

Basically though, you will have to implement `IMultiValueConverter` and use it for your value converter.